# How to use Bluebird .spread in a promise chain

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird, es6-promise

I am using the bluebird library in a node.js app (node 6.10) where I need to chain several promises.

I noticed bluebird has a .spread function that lets you customize the parameters from a ёPromise.all()ё promise, and this works fine if done in place.

```
var promise1 = Promise.promisify(image.getBuffer, {context: image});
var promise2 = Promise.promisify(imageThumb.getBuffer, {context: imageThumb});

Promise
 .all([promise1(Jimp.AUTO), promise2(Jimp.AUTO)])
 .spread(function(buffer, bufferThumb){
   console.log("SPREAD IS A FUNCTION");
 });
```

*This Works!!!

but this:

```
...

  var promise1 = Promise.promisify(image.getBuffer, {context: image});
  var promise2 = Promise.promisify(imageThumb.getBuffer, {context: imageThumb});

  return Promise
    .all([getBufferAsync(Jimp.AUTO), getBufferAsyncThumb(Jimp.AUTO)]);
})
.spread(function(buffer, bufferThumb){

// this never gets called:
console.log("SPREAD IS NOT A FUNCTION");});

...
```

***Doesnt work**, I event get an error in the form:

TypeError: blahbla.read(...).then(...).spread is not a function

I managed a workaround using:

```
...
}).then(function(data){
// use data[0], data[1]
...
```

But what I really want to do is use .spread in the promise chain.  Since I am already using bluebird, I assumed that the Promise returned by Promise.all() is a Bluebird promise and that I can use directly the .spread function. Although it looks like returning a promise to the chain stripes the Bluebird sugar and leaves a simple ES6 promise.

Any thoughts on how to make it work are welcome!

For now I will be using the .then(data), data[0], etc approach.

**The problem is not that the promise wont resolve, the problem is that .spread fails as not being a function in the promise chain. By starting with a function that was originally promisified with Bluebird, the assumption is that the rest of the chain will stick to the Bluebird Promise definition.

Comment: What is `getBufferAsync`?

Comment: That `Promise.all` returns a Bluebird promise doesn't matter. The only relevant thing is the `then` method that creates the promise you're trying to call `spread` on, and that (although not shown) appears not to be the Bluebird one. Start the outer chain with a Bluebird promise.

Comment: Given you're using ES6, you don't need `spread` anyway. Just use array destructuring: `.then(function([buffer, bufferThumb]) { … })`

Comment: I am using Bluebird's
Promise.promisifyAll(Jimp);
... (later on)
Jimp.read(buffer).then(function(image){ // inside here I am returning the Promise.all()
*so my assumption is that the thens are Blubird's

Comment: How would you access the values? something like $0.buffer?

Comment: getBufferAsync is just a function that returns a promise.

Comment: The plain text error is:  Jimp.read(...).then(...).spread is not a function , where Jimp.read() is a function that returns a promise created by Bluebird with Promise.promisifyAll(Jimp)

Comment: No. If you have promisified `Jimp`, then the method which will return a Bluebird promise is `Jimp.readAsync`, which calls `Jimp.read` with a callback. But apparently `Jimp` already supports promises out of the box, so you should use `Bluebird.resolve(Jimp.read(buffer)).then(…)` and not call `promisifyAll`.

Comment: This is it, I totally overlooked that  Jimp.read was originally returning a non-bluebird promise.  After the "casting", this is no longer an issue!, Thankx this makes perfect sense.